# Rotate map with Here Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there any function that allows us to rotate an Here map using the JavaScript API ?

I have found it for android (https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics/maps.html) but I am not able to find it for JavaScript.

If this function does not exist what is the best alternative (still using Here JavaScript API) ?

Comment: I've been unable to find API controls to rotate the map with my own UI or events yet but I have discovered that you can rotate and change view-angle in the browser using ALT + LEFTCLICK DRAG if it's just user interactions that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for rotation isn't very well described but I found an example in the organisation's repo:

https://github.com/heremaps/developer-blog/blob/bef386d743d062275ac976546e3c745932ed8e47/javascript-api-3.1/js/MapRotation.js

You can affect the rotation of a map by setting the `heading` property in the ViewModel:

```
let mapView = map.getViewModel();

mapView.setLookAtData({
  heading: 90
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`H.map.ViewModel.control`

https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-viewmodel.html#h-map-viewmodel__control

It looks like you can control the `angleX` or `angleY` from the ViewModel if you are able to set this somewhere.

Comment: View Model could only be used when using the Street Level Imagery function of sdk. Free rotation for map in Javascript API is not supported at the moment. It is in the works, stay tuned for the latest version of the API.

Comment: @Here Developer Support. - we are a year ahead now. Is the feature available yet?